# Amazon EKS: using spot instances for worker nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

When using AWS EKS, is it possible to set up the worker nodes on spot instances?
how?
Anything I special I should pay attention to, in such a setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by modifying the [Cloudformation Template](https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2018-08-30/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml) (which is mentioned in this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html)) in the `LaunchConfiguration` section to specify a spot price.

```
NodeLaunchConfig:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
  Properties:
    SpotPrice: "20" # <=== Here
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
    ImageId: !Ref NodeImageId
    InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
    KeyName: !Ref KeyName
    SecurityGroups:
    - !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
    BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: !Ref NodeVolumeSize
          VolumeType: gp2
          DeleteOnTermination: true
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          set -o xtrace
          /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${ClusterName} ${BootstrapArguments}
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? \
                   --stack  ${AWS::StackName} \
                   --resource NodeGroup  \
                   --region ${AWS::Region}
```